# Trouble making input and button appear on the right side

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, user-input

I am working on a project where one of the four last tasks is to make a order. I got stuck at making the button appear on where I want it. I am really green at this and to be honest, I have difficulties explaining my needs. But, I'll give it my best.

I wanted to post a picture but because of the reputation level needed, that isn't an option. That would really explain what I want and need in an easy manner.

I'll try and explain how it looks like.
I have a table of three columns, production number, name and price. Everyone of the row as accordingly displaying its data regarding the products. Now, what I need is two inputs, one for the price and one for the rebate. I also need a button for every product in the list.

This is a representation.

```
Prod.no    Name      Price
100        Laser     199     [Input for own price]   [input for rebate]  (Button submit)
```

I thought I could simply use a td and add code for the inputs and button, but that didn't work. I am not even sure if that is possible to accomplish.

Can anyone give a suggestion of how to do this? All of the examples I tried by either google or SO always end up going top of the table instead of where I want it.

Here is the cshtml file responsible and some of the code:

```
model ListModel

@{
IEnumerable<Incendo.Core.Domain.External.ExternalAttribute> cols = (IEnumerable<Incendo.Core.Domain.External.ExternalAttribute>)Model.Aggregates;
}

@if (EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().WorkingCustomer != null)
{
<div class="customerProducts">
    @if (EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().WorkingCustomer.CreditDenied == 1)
    {
        <p class="field-validation-error">Kreditspärr - orderläggning ej möjlig</p>
    }
    else
    {

    var columnIds = cols.Select(m => m.ColumnId).ToList();
    var colNames = cols.Select(m => m.Name).ToList();

    var grid = new WebGrid(
        source: Model.Data,
        columnNames: colNames
        );

    var outString = String.Empty;

    var values = cols.Select(m => m.ExternalAttributeValues).FirstOrDefault();
    if(values != null)
    {
    outString += "<table>";
    var totalCount = values.Count;
    outString += "<thead>";
    outString += "<tr>";
    foreach(var name in colNames)
    {
        if (name != "Prod. typ")
        {
            outString += "<th>" + name + "</th>";

        }            
    }
    //outString += "<th>" + "Beställning" + "</th>";

    outString += "</tr>";
    outString += "</thead>";
    outString += "<tbody>";

    for(int row = 0; row < values.Count; row++)
    {

        outString += "<tr>";
        for (int name = 0; name < columnIds.Count; name++)
        {
            var col = cols.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ColumnId == columnIds[name]);
            if (col.Column.TextTypeNo > 0)
            {
                //outString = outString + String.Format("<td>[{0}] +++ {1}</td>", col.ExternalAttributeKeyValues[row].Key, col.ExternalAttributeKeyValues[row].Value);                        
            }
            else
            {
                outString = outString + String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", col.ExternalAttributeKeyValues[row].Value);                                                
            }                    
        }
        var prodNr = cols.ElementAt(0).ExternalAttributeKeyValues[row].Value;
        //outString += String.Format("<td> <input type=\"submit\" />    {0}</td>", prodNr);
        //outString += String.Format("<td> <input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Lägg\" />    {0}</td>", prodNr);           

        outString += "<td>"
            + "<input type=\"submit\" />"
            +"</td>";

        //outString += "<input type=\"submit\" />";

        outString += "</tr>";
    }
outString += "</tbody>";

outString += "</table>";
}


@Html.Raw(outString)
    }
</div>
}
```

I am quite sure the code isn't necessary since it only returns some externalattributes (prod. no, name, price etc.)
My plan is to use the id of the product as the identifier of the button and that way use the two inputs, if a user has written something in them, and make the order.

I have seen something with Html.BeginForm but since I believe that in order for a order to pass through, the inputs must be passed to an actioncontroller and to the actionmethod responsible for the buttonclick.

Hopefully someone can give me a hint to where I am doing wrong. I don't really think this should be such a problem, but I am new to all this.

Below is output of it all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"> 
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/fastclick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Mobile/Incendo.UI.Menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/public.common.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <menu id="menu">
        <ul class="t-widget t-reset t-header t-menu" id="Admin"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Mina sidor<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/">Dashboard</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Produkter<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Product/List">Produkter</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Product/Search">S&#246;k produkt</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Leverant&#246;rer<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Supplier/List">Leverant&#246;rer</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Kunder<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Customer/List">Kunder</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Customer/Create">Ny kund</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Customer/Search">S&#246;k kund</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">F&#246;rs&#228;ljning<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Orders/List">S&#246;k order</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/ShoppingCart/Cart">Aktuell order</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Inst&#228;llningar<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Settings/Customer">Kund</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Anv&#228;ndare<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/User/List">Anv&#228;ndare</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">System<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Common/SystemInfo">Systeminformation</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Common/ClearCache">Rensa cache</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Common/RestartApplication">Starta om applikation</a></li></ul></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><span class="t-link">Mina inst&#228;llningar<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></span><ul class="t-group"><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/User/Settings">Inst&#228;llningar</a></li><li class="t-item t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="/Account/Logout">Logga ut</a></li></ul></li></ul><script type="text/javascript">
//    $(document).ready(function () {
//        $("#Admin").kendoMenu();
//    });
</script>
    </menu>
    <section id="pagebody" data-role="page" class="pages ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active container" id="home" data-url="home">

    <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
            <a href="#" class="showMenu" data-theme="a">Menu</a>
            <div class="login-info">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="dialog-notifications-success" title="Common.Notification" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="dialog-notifications-error" title="Fel" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="bar-notification" class="bar-notification">
    <img src="/Content/Images/ico-close-notification-bar.png" class="close" alt="Close" title="Close" />
</div>
                    <div data-role="content-header" class="">
            <div class="userinfobar">
            <h1>UserInfoBar.cshtml</h1>
            <form action="/Common/FirmSelected?Length=6" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="onFirmChangedRequestCompleted();" id="form-firmselector" method="post"><select id="userfirm" name="userfirm" onChange="onFirmChanged();"><option value="3">F0002 - BB</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">F0001 - BB AB</option>
</select></form>    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onFirmChanged() {
            $("#form-firmselector").submit();
        }
        function onFirmChangedRequestCompleted() {
            location.reload();
        }
    </script>

0                 <div id="workingCustomerSection-active">
                    <p>Aktuell kund</p>

                        <p><a href="/Customer/Details/100001">Cykellagret AB</a></p>


                    <a class="button" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-success="clearWorkingCustomerSuccess" href="/User/ClearWorkingCustomer/0">Anv&#228;nd inte aktuell kund</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearWorkingCustomerSuccess(e) {
        handleResponse(e);
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
                </div>
            </div>                        
                    </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
            <div class="ajax-loading-block-window" style="display: none">
                <div class="loading-image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Cykellagret AB</h2>

<section id="custhead" class="clearfix">    
    <dl class="table-display">
        <dt>Kundnr</dt>
        <dd>100001</dd>
        <dt>Adress</dt>
        <dd>Strandv&#228;gen 4</dd>
        <dt>Telefonnr</dt>
        <dd>99887766</dd>
    </dl>
</section>
<h1>Details.cshtml</h1>
<div id="buttonbar">


<a class="button" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-success="clearWorkingCustomerSuccess" href="/User/ClearWorkingCustomer/0">Anv&#228;nd inte aktuell kund</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearWorkingCustomerSuccess(e) {
        handleResponse(e);
        location.reload();
    }
</script><a href="tel:99887766" class="phone button">Ring</a>
</div>

<div id="tabStrip">
    <ul>
        <li>Leveransinfo</li>        <li>Kundgrupp</li>        <li>S&#228;ljare</li>        <li>Kontaktpersoner</li>        <li>Sortiment</li>        <li>Avtal</li>        <li>&#214;ppna kundposter</li>        <li>Aktiviteter</li>        <li>Produkter</li>    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <dl class="table-display">
            <dt>Ledtid</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Leveransdagar</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Orderstopptid</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Namn</dt>
            <dd>Cykellagret AB</dd>
            <dt>3PL Kundnummer</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>3PL Status</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Kreditsp&#228;rr</dt>
            <dd>0</dd>
        </dl>               
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <dl class="table-display">
            <dt>Kedjetillh&#246;righet</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Kategori</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Kundstatus</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Kundkategori</dt>
            <dd></dd>
        </dl>               
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <dl class="table-display">
            <dt>S&#228;ljare</dt>
            <dd>120</dd>
            <dt>Senaste kontakt</dt>
            <dd></dd>
        </dl>               
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">

    <button type="button" id="createContactButton">Ny kontaktperson</button>
    <table id="contacts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Namn</th>
                <th>Telefon</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Marie H&#246;ljer</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Carl von Friesenwind</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div id="createContactWindow"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        var btn = $("#createContactButton");
        btn.click(
        function(){
            initKendoWindow();
            var window = $("#createContactWindow").data("kendoWindow").open();
            window.center();
            window.refresh('/Customer/CreateContactPerson/1001');
            btn.hide();
        });
        var onClose = function () {
            btn.show();
        }
        function initKendoWindow() {
            if (!$("#createContactWindow").data("kendoWindow")) {
                $("#createContactWindow").kendoWindow({
                    title: 'Skapa kontaktperson',
                    visible: false,
                    modal: true,
                    close: onClose
                }).data("kendoWindow");
            }
        }
    })
        </script>


            </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    <p>Assortment.NoAssortment</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".assortmentbox").change(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        customerNo: 100001,
                        family: this.id.split('_')[0],
                        status: this.id.split('_')[1],
                        enabled: this.checked
                    }),
                    url: "/Assortment/ChangeStatus",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <dl class="table-display">
            <dt>Avtal med</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Till datum</dt>
            <dd>0</dd>
            <dt>Grossist</dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt>Bryggeri</dt>
            <dd></dd>
        </dl>               
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">


<table><thead><tr><th>Fakt. nr</th><th>Reg. datum</th><th>Belopp</th><th>Restbelopp</th><th>Förf. datum</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="field-validation-error">98500040</td><td class="field-validation-error">20080924</td><td class="field-validation-error">3664,05</td><td class="field-validation-error">3664,05</td><td class="field-validation-error">20081004</td></tr><tr><td class="field-validation-error">98500029</td><td class="field-validation-error">20080716</td><td class="field-validation-error">13591,23</td><td class="field-validation-error">13591,23</td><td class="field-validation-error">20080726</td></tr><tr><td>98500002</td><td>20081211</td><td>918,75</td><td>918,75</td><td>20130801</td></tr><tr><td class="field-validation-error">98100148</td><td class="field-validation-error">20081222</td><td class="field-validation-error">281288</td><td class="field-validation-error">281288</td><td class="field-validation-error">20070121</td></tr><tr><td class="field-validation-error">98100120</td><td class="field-validation-error">20081009</td><td class="field-validation-error">6638</td><td class="field-validation-error">6638</td><td class="field-validation-error">20081108</td></tr></tbody></table>    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">

<button type="button" id="createAppointmentButton" class="button">Ny aktivitet</button>
<div id="window"></div>
Inga aktiviteter ännu på kunden<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var btn = $('#createAppointmentButton');
        btn.click(
        function () {
            initKendoWindow();
            var window = $("#window").data("kendoWindow").open();
            window.center();
            window.refresh('/Appointments/CreateAppointment/100001/');
            btn.hide();
        });
        var onClose = function () {
            btn.show();
        }
        function initKendoWindow() {
            if (!$("#window").data("kendoWindow")) {
                $("#window").kendoWindow({
                    title: 'Skapa aktivitet',
                    visible: false,
                    modal: true,
                    close: onClose
                }).data("kendoWindow");
            }
        }
    })
</script>    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">


    <div class="customerProducts">
<table><thead><tr><th>Prod. nr</th><th>Namn</th><th>Pris</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1000</td><td>PRODUKT LAGERFÖRD (MALL)</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>1010</td><td>PRODUKT EJ LAGERFÖRD (MALL)</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>Celerifere</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>111</td><td>Framhjul, komplett modell landsväg</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>112</td><td>Framhjul, komplett modell mountain</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>113</td><td>Bakhjul, komplett modell landsväg</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>114</td><td>Bakhjul, komplett modell mountain</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>115</td><td>Mono-hjul</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>Sauerbronn</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>121</td><td>Ram, landsväg</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>122</td><td>Ram, mountain</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>Ram, mono</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>Vector</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>131</td><td>Kraftöverföringspaket Eddy</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>1311</td><td>Pedal</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>1312</td><td>Kedja</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>1313</td><td>Kugghjul</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>132</td><td>Kraftöverföringspaket Alfredo</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>133</td><td>Kraftöverföringspaket Harry</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>134</td><td>Kraftöverföringspaket mono</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>141</td><td>Styranordning Leon</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>142</td><td>Styranordning Drais</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>143</td><td>Styranordning Karl</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>151</td><td>Sadel Gösta</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>152</td><td>Sadel Bernt</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>153</td><td>Sadel Ronaldo</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>154</td><td>Sadel mono</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>161</td><td>Dekalpaket Celerifere</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>162</td><td>Dekalpaket Sauerbronn</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>163</td><td>Dekalpaket Vector</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>164</td><td>Dekalpaket Dandy-horse</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>165</td><td>Dekalpaket Michaux</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>166</td><td>Dekalpaket Singleton</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>171</td><td>Pakethållare Backpack</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>200</td><td>Debiterbar tid</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>201</td><td>Arbetstimmar service</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>22</td><td>Michaux</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>23</td><td>Singleton</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr><tr><td>505</td><td>Testprodukt</td><td>0</td><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr></tbody></table>    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip();
    });
</script>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

I managed to get what I wanted with this code added, but it is indeed ugly.

```
outString += "<td>"
            + "<label>Överstyrt pris</label>"
            + "<label>Rabatt (%)</label>"
            + "<input type=\"text\" id=\"overridePrice" + prodNr + "\" value=\"0\" >"
            + "<input type=\"text\" id=\"rebate" + prodNr + "\" value=\"0\" >"
            + "<button type=\"button\" id=\"addOrder" + prodNr + "\" ONCLICK=\"window.location.href=\'/CustomerProducts/AddProductToCart\'\" class=\"button\">Lägg</button>"
            + ""
            +"</td>";
```

This is the only way of making the input fields and buttons appear where I want them to. I don't know much CSS, so this will have to do.
The onclick-thing is horrendous, but ajax or jscript isn't possible with this approach.

Comment: Look at the page source (the resulting html from all of your code) does it look right? Tables shouldn't have any difficulty accomplishing what you want (assuming I understand it right) so my guess is your code isn't building the html like you think it is.

Comment: @lostphilosopher I think it ok. It is really hard for me to tell. I'll update my post with the output.

Comment: Yikes. Which is the button that is out of place? If it's this one (<button type="button" id="createAppointmentButton" class="button">Ny aktivitet</button>) then that would make sense since it is out of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you completely, but if you wish to have multiple buttons on your page, I recommend using the button html element, rather than "input type='submit'". That way, you can have as many as you want.

See here for info on the button element:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: Hi Krayg. That is my problem too. It doesn't help wheter I use that either, the output is the same. Something that resembles a button or an input-field, but without being able to click on the button or make som input in the input-field.

Comment: Hi Krayg. With some more thinking and other posts, I managed to get this working...somewhat...and very ugly indeed. But, to be honest, I am not even sure if it is possible to do otherwise. Please take a look at the edits above.